# How to set and get TestStep properties in SoapUI using Java

Tags: java, soapui

I am trying to set the properties of SOAPUI TestStep inside SOAPUI Project in Java as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

When I debug the below code, I am always getting null when I `getProperty` or `setPropertyValue`. My point is I want to set the property variable from a java function which I couldn't able to do it. I am getting help in Groovy when I google the problem. Can some one help me how to do this in Java

```
public class SoapUITest
{
   public final static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {

    WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject("C:\\users\\vikram\\WebService\\WebServiceTest\\src\\main\\java\\weather.xml");
    WsdlTestSuite wsdlTestSuite = project.getTestSuiteByName("WeatherZip");
    WsdlTestCase wsdlTestCase = wsdlTestSuite.getTestCaseByName("Weatherbyzip");
    WsdlTestStep wsdlTestStep = wsdlTestCase.getTestStepByName("GetCityForecastByZIP");
    wsdlTestStep.setPropertyValue("City","21001");// Problem: Unable to set the property value
    WsdlTestCaseRunner wsdlTestCaseRunner = new WsdlTestCaseRunner(wsdlTestCase, new StringToObjectMap(wsdlTestCase.getProperties()));

    TestStepResult testStepResult = wsdlTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(wsdlTestStep);
    if (testStepResult instanceof WsdlTestRequestStepResult) {
        System.out.println(((WsdlTestRequestStepResult) testStepResult).getResponse().getContentAsString());
    }
  }
}
```

I want to set the value of the city on fly while executing the program. Please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 1):

Alright.. I have figured it out myself by adding custom properties in TestCase level instead of TestStep.

`wsdlTestCase.setPropertyValue("City","12345");`

Now the SoapUI request body Partlooks like this

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <weat:GetCityForecastByZIP>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <weat:ZIP>${#TestCase#City}</weat:ZIP>
  </weat:GetCityForecastByZIP>
</soapenv:Body>
```